# Compiler returns error after calling class from other file

Tags: c++, class, error-handling, include

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I did make the properties setup for the path. This file should be a transition from the winning/losing battle menu into a new fight for the user. I want to call it in my main file, but when I compile the main file, I get the same error as in the cpp file contaning this class. I did try to change the position of `#pragma` and move my `#include` of the cpp file first, but it still didn't work (I did this because I found it on Microsoft's offical site).

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "BattleMenu.cpp"
using namespace std;

class MenuTransition
{
public:
    int user_input;

    void transition()
    {
        cout << "You are encoutering a new enemy" <</*EnemyName*/endl;
        cout << "Press ENTER to continue..." << endl;
        cin >> user_input;
        BattleMenu menu;
        system("cls");
    }

    MenuTransition()
    {
        transition();
    }

    ~MenuTransition(){}
};
```

```
error C2065: 'BattleMenu': undeclared identifier
syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'menu'
error C2065: 'menu': undeclared identifier
```

Comment: You probably want `#include "BattleMenu.h"`? Including cpp files is almost always incorrect.

Comment: Same error as with cpp

Answer (score 0):

You should make hpp file of BattleMenu file and include it like `#include "BattleMenu.hpp"`